# SQL Select and Update command

Tags: sql

I need to update a column using the update statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM tng_managedobject 
WHERE severity <> 0 
  AND class_name like 'Plaza_VES_Junction_Box' 
  AND propagate_status <> 0
```

I need to update the `propagate_status` for all these classes to 0. How can I use the SQL update statement to do this?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple update statement like this will do it:

```
update tng_managedobject 
set propagate_status = 0
where severity <> 0 
    and class_name = 'Plaza_VES_Junction_Box'
    and propagate_status <> 0
```

You don't need a `LIKE` clause when you are specifying the exact class name. `=` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
update tng_managedobject
set propagate_status = 0
where severity <> 0 
and class_name like '%Plaza_VES_Junction_Box%' 
and propagate_status <> 0
```

For the class_name column, If you know the exact name, it is better to use `=`. If you are looking for a string that contains `Plaza_VES_Junction_Box` anywhere use `%`

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.propagate_status = 0
FROM tng_managedobject AS table1
WHERE table1.severity <> 0 
AND table1.class_name like '%Plaza_VES_Junction_Box%' 
AND table1.propagate_status <> 0
```

Comment: Curious thing that you changed the pattern for `like` to include wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tng_managedobject
SET propagate_status = 0
WHERE severity <> 0 AND class_name like('Plaza_VES_Junction_Box')
```

As @zedfoxus points out, you don't need a `like` statement. To maintain difference in answers, use his since it is more efficient than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tng_managedobject set  propagate_status=0    
where severity <> 0 and class_name like 'Plaza_VES_Junction_Box' 
and propagate_status <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tng_managedobject 
set propagate_status = 0 
where severity <> 0
and class_name like 'Plaza_VES_Junction_Box'
and propagate_status <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tng_managedobject 
set propagate_status = 0
where severity <> 0 
  and class_name = 'Plaza_VES_Junction_Box'
  and propagate_status <> 0
```

Comment: update tablename(as mentioned in question)
set columnname=value
where <conditions(as given in question)>

No need to use Like operator as the expression is 'Plaza_VES_Junction_Box' .like opr had worked well if expression would have '%Plaza_VES_Junction_Box%'.that's why I replaced that with '='